# Github Zen mode editing with fixed-width font?

Tags: github, zen

Is there a way to tell Github Zen mode (full screen text editor) to use a fixed-width font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Firefox with Stylish:

```css
@-moz-document domain(github.com) {
  #fullscreen-contents {
    font-family: Consolas;
  }
}
```

[Source](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/acbed85/firefox/public.css#L11-L18)